# HTACCESS Redirect not redirecting a certain page to another websites URL

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am editing an .HTACCESS file to redirect a link https://www.example.com/activity/siag_chair.php  to a new link on another site https://www.newsite.org/newlink

The website is on a LAMP stack.

I will post below the examples I have tried. None have worked. But the 404 to /arc404.php. So I know the htaccess file at least works.

Example 1 :

```
RewriteEngine On
RedirectMatch 301/activity/siag_chair.php https://www.newsite.org/newlink
ErrorDocument 404 /arc404.php
```

Example 2 :

```
RewriteEngine On
Redirect 301 /activity/siag_chair.php https://www.newsite.org/newlink
ErrorDocument 404 /arc404.php
```

Example 3 :

```
RewriteEngine On
Redirect https://www.example.com/activity/siag_chair.php https://www.newsite.org/newlink
ErrorDocument 404 /arc404.php
```

I am honestly not sure whats wrong or what else to try.... Any advice on what to try next will help. thx!

Comment: in your first example you need a space between 301 and the actual link. it should be 301 /activity/siag_chair.php

Comment: did you enable your mod_rewrite?

Comment: also you need to do this in your httpd.conf file <Directory /path/to/dir/>
  AllowOverride All
</Directory>, if you've done all that your redirect should work

Comment: Im going to do research into these suggestions. I am working on a website I didn't build thats on a server hosting many sites. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: Do you have any other directives in your `.htaccess` file? Do you have any other `.htaccess` files? Note that `RewriteEngine` refers to mod_rewrite, whereas `Redirect` and `RedirectMatch` are both mod_alias directives - so these are unrelated, you should delete the `RewriteEngine` directive if you are not using mod_rewrite. However, this is not the cause of your problem.

Comment: Can you update your question with your complete .htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, inside the htaccess, you don't see the leading "/", as you would in the apache configuration files.  Try

```
RedirectMatch 301 activity/siag_chair.php https://www.newsite.org/newlink
```

Watch out, for RedirectMatch expects a regex as second parameter.

Comment: You should have a leading slash when using the `RedirectMatch` directive. You only omit the leading slash when using mod_rewrite `RewriteRule` in a _directory_ or `.htaccess` context.